# Simple ng-show directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a very simple application:

I want to load an array via ajax call, then display it. During the loading time, I want an animated gif.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="thresholdApp">
<head lang="fr">
    <script src="/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bin/js/thresholds/angular/controller/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="/bin/js/thresholds/angular/service/webservice.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="thresholdCtrl as ctrl" class="text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column small-6 small-centered">
            <table>
                    <tr ng-show="loading">
                        <td colspan="3" class="text-center">
                            <img src="/res/img/greyLoadingWheel.gif" alt="loading"/>
                            {{loading}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="t in thresholds">
                        <td>{{t.brand.name}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{t.stock}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{t.threshold}}</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With that controller :

```
thresholdApp = angular.module("thresholdApp", []);

thresholdApp.controller("thresholdCtrl",function($scope, webService) {

    $scope.loading = true;
    webService.post("stock/threshold/check", {}, function(result) {
        $scope.thresholds = result.stockThresholds;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

It works well, the table is filled with the ajax response as expected but the tr with the ng-show directive don't work. The weird thing is that in the other hand, {{loading}} is well updated and is replace by false.

ng-show seems to do nothing and the tr is always displayed.

Any idea ?

---

#### EDIT

Changing `ng-show` by `ng-if` works. But does anyone knows why `ng-show` doesn't work here ?

Comment: Are you setting 'loading=true' anywhere in your controller?

Comment: ``$scope.loading`` is always false. This might be the reason.

Comment: In which moment do you set the loading bool to true?

Comment: @Kangcor Sorry, edited

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin Can you try to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` and see if it actually shows/hide the gif?

Comment: @Kangcor It works ! But why ng-show doesn't works ?

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin I can't say 100% sure, but i think that `ng-show/hide` only sets the `display: none` attribute, and `ng-if` actually removes the element from the DOM. So i think is something related to the `display: none` in the `<tr>` and not something with **angular** itself.

Comment: @Kangcor Yes it seems that the css class `ng-hide` is not defined... Not any idea why... But you can post as response, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, seems like the error is related to the attribute `display: none` in the `<tr>` when the `ng-show/hide` directive is set.

Using the `ng-if` directive removes it effectively from the DOM and works as expected.

---

For some reasons, angular don't set his css classes.

The fix, as said in the angular documentation, is to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/angular-csp.css"/>
```

Comment: Display none on TR tag works well even in old IE. So it can be something with OP's project specific thing.

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I have found that the problem was the css angular classes were not loaded properly. It's chrome CSP related problem I think.